# iOS not playing html5 videos

Tags: python, ios, django, html

I built a lan video server using Django. I use the video tag to play videos, so no extra players need to be installed. The videos play quite well in other platforms like windows or android, but it doesn’t work on my iPhone, no matter the size or format of the video file.

Moreover, when I use wireshark to analyze the data packages, I found out that the data is transferred correctly at the beginning, but the client closed the socket connection immediately. It’s quite bizarre. 
Can anyone help me figure out what’s going wrong here. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Ps: I edited it on my phone, so sorry for the terrible format.

the code for the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<video controls autoplay>
<source src="/media/{{file_path}}" type="video/mp4"> </source>
</video>
<li><a href="/media/{{file_path}}">{{file_name}}</a></li>
</body>
</html>
```

[the log of django:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0que.png)

[the data package from wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qp3i.png)

Comment: are you using autoplay?

Comment: yes, and I've just posted the video html page on the question description.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of the Policy Restriction of the `<video>` tag under IOS:

https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/